# How to disable past dates from selected date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using picakdate datepicker plugin. I have two datepicker fields from_date and to_date. I just want to disable past dates inside to_date field from selected date in from_date field. I had tried some code. But it didnt work. I want to achieve this on selection on from_date field.
I have tried following code :

```
function disable_to_date(input_value)
{

var date_array = input_value.split(" ");
var month1 = date_array[1];
month1 = month1.trim().replace(/["~!@#$%^&*\(\)_+=`{}\[\]\|\\:;'<>,.\/?"\- \t\r\n]+/g, '');
month1 = month1.toLowerCase();
var months = ["january", "february", "march", "april", "may", "june", "july", "august", "september", "octomber", "november", "december"];
month1 = months.indexOf(month1);
month1 = month1+1;
var final_date = date_array[2]+","+month1+","+date_array[0];
$('.end_date').pickadate({
   min: [final_date]
});
}
```

my function disable_to_date accept one parameter that is date selected in from_date field and it is on following format: 8 June, 2016

Comment: They have given proper example for that.. **[Check it out](http://codepen.io/amsul/pen/nGckA)**

Comment: Thanks a lot.. It works.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding..

Comment: One more question. what should I use in case of from , to time picker